# Arduino as ISP programming the Arduino, not the connected ATmega328P

Tags: arduino, atmega, isp

I am trying to program an ATmega328P with an Arduino Uno R3. When I click 'Upload to Programmer' in the Arduino IDE (version 1.0.5), the Arduino programs itself and not the chip. Stranger still, the ArduinoISP sketch continues to run on the Arduino as well as the program that should've been burned to the chip. Here are the steps I take:

*ArduinoISP sketch is open*

1. Tools > Boards > Arduino UNO
2. Tools > Programmer > AVRISP mkII
3. File > Upload

*Upload successfully completes*

4. File > Examples > 01.Basics > Blink
5. Tools > Boards > Arduino Nano w/ ATmega328
6. Tools > Programmer > Arduino as ISP
7. File > Upload Using Programmer

*No AVRDUDE errors, upload appears to have successfully completed*

After I take these steps, the Arduino still has the ArduinoISP heartbeat LED beating, but the pin 13 'L' LED is also blinking on and off, just like in the Blink sketch. This persists even if the Arduino is manually reset; it's as if the Arduino has 2 sketches running at once. The LED connected to pin 13 on the ATmega328P does not blink.

Here is my wiring:

[image: Wiring]

**NOTE: There is also a 10uF electrolyte capacitor the Uno's between RESET (+) and GND (-) which was missed off the above diagram.**

Can anybody help me program this ATmega328P? I have tried 2 different chips, and both have had the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If your target AVR is an Atmega328P, why are you using "Tools > Boards > Arduino Nano w/ ATmega328" and not "Tools > Boards > Arduino UNO"? If you have the ArduinoISP sketch uploaded and running on the UNO and "Arduino as ISP" selected as the programmer, it should all work.

An Arduino R3 should not need the 10uF capacitor on its RESET pin but it does no harm but remember, if you leave the capacitor in place, you can't upload to the UNO. I suggest that you start with a fresh upload of the ArduinoISP sketch to the UNO, attach the capacitor to prevent the UNO resetting and then just upload the Blink sketch to the target using "Upload using programmer" with "Arduino as ISP" selected. Make sure that the COM port is the COM port for your UNO though!

I know you have done this but it is important to use the "Arduino UNO" board type. Oh, by the way, it's a good idea to put a 10K resistor connected to VCC on the RESET pin of the target AVR.

Answer (score -1):

I also started to program AVR.

As far as I learned from my research, you need a bootloader burned on those chips, and you need a hardware to do that.

If you already did that, you need to program the Arduino UNO to act as a an ISP. To do, go Arduino IDE >> File >> Examples >> Arduino ISP and burn that code into ARDUINO!

After that when you put the "Makefile" and the ".c" file into a folder, you need to open the command prompt and flash them into the chip.

Comment: This is not a meaningful answer, as you are describing the same steps the poster has *already* listed in their question.

Comment: Please read the first part of question and the answer again carefully.

Comment: Not understanding the answer does not give you the right to downvote.

Comment: The first part of this answer is incorrect. No bootloader is required on the ISP target.

Comment: Yeah I am sure...

Comment: The chips were purchased with an Optiboot bootloader pre installed.

Comment: @OrangeFlash81 Thank you for the information. If I could not help you, I am sorry. I am like a beginner just like you. Maybe I should have written a comment, not an answer. But the thing you are doing is trying to upload your code to the Arduino. In this task Sketch's usage is only for programming Arduino not the other chip. After you turn it into ISP, you have to have an IDE like WinAvr to write your code in c, create a Makefile and upload those to the chip using serial port through Arduino.